# Similarity search with text and tabular data

Tags: similarity, embeddings

If I have two documents, `D1` and `D2` and a function `f` which computes the (normalized) document embedding `E1 = f(D1)` then I can get the cosine similarity by `E1 @ E2` (with "@" being the dot-product). This is a fast and easy to way to get top `N` most similar documents.

Now, say I have additional data like e.g publishing date and price (just to take an example) that I want to incorporate in the similarity; are there any "usual" way to compute the similarity between `D1` and `D2` with this additional data in "one go"? I could make one vector consisting of `[text_embedding, price, day_in_year]`, normalize that vector and again taking the dot product between these new vectors.

I do see several issues with this one being the text-embedding consists of e.g 1024 dimensions thus it would clearly dominate the dot product thus the price/publish date might not make such a big difference (if any).

I could of course make some weighted similarity/distance between the text, the price and the publishing date, but since I would like to store those vectors in a vectordatabase such that I can do some some similarity search (e.g with `pgvector`), it is really not my first choice .

It seems like `multimodal embedding` ([example](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/model-reference/multimodal-embeddings)) is what I'm looking for, but I can't find that much litterature on how it is done.